# Vuejs human time component taking too much of CPU

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datetime

This is a simple component that turns a timestamp into relative time text:

```
Vue.component('human-time', {
  props: ['time'],
  methods: {
    format(time){ 
      const formats = [
        [60, 'seconds', 1],
        [120, '1 minute'],
        [3600, 'minutes', 60],
        [7200, '1 hour'],
        [86400, 'hours', 3600],
        [172800, '1 day'],
        [604800, 'days', 86400],
        [1209600, '1 week'],
        [2419200, 'weeks', 604800],
        [4838400, '1 month'],
        [29030400, 'months', 2419200],
        [58060800, '1 year'],
        [2903040000, 'years', 29030400]
      ];

      time = +new Date(time);

      let s = (+new Date() - time) / 1000;
      if(s === 0)
        return 'Just now';

      if(s < 0)
        s = Math.abs(s);

      for(const[limit, text, one] of formats)
        if(s < limit)
          return one ? Math.floor(s / one) + ' ' + text : text;

      return time;    
    }

  },

  render(createElement){

    // update human time every second
    this.intv = setInterval(() => this.$el.textContent = this.format(this.time), 1000);

    const localTime = (new Date(this.time)).toString();
    return createElement('time', { attrs : { datetime: this.time, title: localTime }}, this.format(this.time));
  },

  beforeDestroy(){
    clearInterval(this.intv);
  }

});
```

Usage is like this:

```
<human-time :time="entry.time"></human-time>
```

Problem is that on many entries (500+) it it makes the browser (Chrome only) use a lot of CPU.
I suspect it's because Chrome can't handle well that many timers. Any suggestions on how can I solve this  issue, while keeping the relative time constantly up to date?

Comment: don't put `setInterval` into render, put it into `mounted()` because `render()` will be called every time of VNodes are updated. and if possible, don't directly change Dom like `this.$el.textContent`, uses `{{time}}` or `v-bind:time` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are **some improvements**:

1. move `setInterval` from `render()` to `mounted()` because `render()` will be called when every update which causes creating tons of `interval`. Check [Vue: Life cycle diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) from more details.
2. add one data property to save current formatted time, so you don't need to manually change Dom text content by `this.$el.textContent`.
3. add one watch to sync latest props=`time` to the data property=`current`

**PS:** I added one console.log into `render()`, then you will see why it is really a bad idea and causes high cpu usage when put `setInterval` into `render()`.

```js
Vue.component('human-time', {
  props: ['time'],
  methods: {
    format(time){ 
      const formats = [
        [60, 'seconds', 1],
        [120, '1 minute'],
        [3600, 'minutes', 60],
        [7200, '1 hour'],
        [86400, 'hours', 3600],
        [172800, '1 day'],
        [604800, 'days', 86400],
        [1209600, '1 week'],
        [2419200, 'weeks', 604800],
        [4838400, '1 month'],
        [29030400, 'months', 2419200],
        [58060800, '1 year'],
        [2903040000, 'years', 29030400]
      ];

      time = +new Date(time);

      let s = (+new Date() - time) / 1000;
      if(s === 0)
        return 'Just now';

      if(s < 0)
        s = Math.abs(s);

      for(const[limit, text, one] of formats)
        if(s < limit)
          return one ? Math.floor(s / one) + ' ' + text : text;

      return time;    
    }

  },
  data () {
    return {
      current: this.format(this.time)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    time: function (newVal) {
      this.current = this.format(newVal)
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.intv = setInterval(() => this.current = this.format(this.time), 1000);
  },
  render(createElement){

    // update human time every second
    
    console.log('ex: rendering')
    const localTime = (new Date(this.time)).toString();
    return createElement('span', { attrs : { datetime: this.time, title: localTime }}, this.current);
  },

  beforeDestroy(){
    clearInterval(this.intv);
  }

})

new Vue ({
  el:'#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <human-time :time="new Date()"></human-time>
        <human-time :time="new Date() - 120000"></human-time>
    </div>
</div>
```